# D3 visualization responsive to all screen sizes without scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

How can I get a basic line graph to fit on any device screens without a scroll bar appearing on the screen? I have already included the following 2 statements in my code:

```
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 width height")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
```

This has resolved the horizontal scroll bar to appear on the screen but I am still getting a vertical scroll bar on my laptop screen although it works fine on the desktop screen. 
Also the axis disappears on screen zoom in zoom out.

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/arnica04/937WE/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css a bit:

```
body 
{ 
  font: 12px Arial; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  position:absolute; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  overflow:hidden
}
```

Some of that could be considered unnecessary.  The quickest and dirtiest is just to add the `overflow:hidden`

Comment: hey...its working fine in Chrome. But not in Mozilla Firefox! Is there an alternative way of achieving the required output?